# How to condition a computation and then add al computation done in R?

Tags: r

i am experimenting with and R and I can't find the way to do the next thing:

1- I want to multiply if x == 3 multiply by "y" value of the same row
 2- Add all computations done in step 1.

```
  x <- 3426278722533992028364647392927338
  y <- 7479550949037487987438746984798374
  x <- as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(x), "")[[1]])
  y <- as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(y), "")[[1]])
  Table <- table(x,y)
  Table <- data.frame(Table)

  Table$Freq <- NULL
```

So I tried creating a function:

```
  Calculation <- function (x,y) {

  z <- if(x == 3){ x * y }

  w <- sum(z)

  }
```

## x and y are the columns of the data.frame

This prints and error which I struggle to solve...

Thanks for your time,

Kylian Pattje

Comment: You should define x as a string. The way it is defined right now will result in `NA`. That is, defining it as a number then using `as.character` will give you `3.42627872253399e+33` for `x`. You should then use `ifelse` instead of `if`.

Comment: `with(subset(Table, x == 3), sum(x*y))` is another option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things here:

**1.** Use `ifelse` in your function,

```
Calculation <- function (x,y) {
  z <- ifelse(x == 3, x * y, NA)
  w <- sum(z, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(w)
}
```

**2.** Make sure your variables are NOT factors,

```
Table[] <- lapply(Table, function(i) as.numeric(as.character(i)))

Calculation(Table$x, Table$y)
#[1] 84
```

Comment: It did work!! I have to study lapply and learn how it works!! Thanks for the help!